# This page cannot be Displayed /•Make sure the web address http://localhost:8080 is correct

Tags: jsp, servlets

> This page cannot be Displayed? •Make sure the web address
>   http://localhost:8080 is correct.
>
> ```
> When i Debug my File Uploading Program I Face this type of Error    I run this Code in chrome ,chrome work but when i debug this code
> ```
>
> ,chrome throws this page cannot display?
>
> Index.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    
    
    
    
    Insert title here
    
    
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                ID:
                                
                            
                                
                                Name:
                                
                            
                                
                                Image:
                                
                            
                                
                                
                                SeeResult

> Result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Upload Demo In JSP & Servlet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result">
            <img alt="demo" src="images/id.png" height="200" width="150">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> ImageProcess.java

```
enter code here

package com.service;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

public class ImageProcess {
    private static final int IMG_WIDTH=400;
    private static final int IMG_HEIGHT=300;

    public static boolean processfile(FileItem item,String ImgName,String path){
        try {
        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
        File f = new File(path+File.separator+name);
            item.write(f);
            //This code help you resize and rename your code
            File resizefile = new File(path+File.separator+ImgName);
            BufferedImage orginalImage=ImageIO.read(f);
            int type = orginalImage.getType() ==0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB:orginalImage.getType();
            BufferedImage resizeImagePng = resizeImage(orginalImage,type);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImagePng,"png", resizefile);
            f.delete();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage orginalImage,int type){
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(orginalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }

}
```

> FileUploadResizeRename.java

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import com.service.ImageProcess;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FileUploadResizeRename
 */
@WebServlet("/FileUploadResizeRename")
public class FileUploadResizeRename extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name, ImgName;
    private static final String path="D:/HypoThesis/WebContent/images";

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FileUploadResizeRename() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            List<FileItem> multiparts;

            try {
                multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for(FileItem item: multiparts){
                    if(item.isFormField()){
                    String fieldname= item.getFieldName();
                    String value= item.getString();
                    if(fieldname.equals("id")){
                        id = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    }else if(fieldname.equals("name")){
                        name= value;
                    }
                    out.println(fieldname+":"+value+"</br>");
                    }else{
                        ImgName=id +".png";
                        if(ImageProcess.processfile(item, ImgName, path)){
                            out.println(ImgName+"upload successfull");
                        }else{
                            out.println("file upload failed");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Sorry this is only for file upload");
        }
    }

}
```

> FileUploadHandler.java

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FileUploadResizeRename
 */
@WebServlet("/FileUploadResizeRename")
public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY="d:/AllFolder/images";

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FileUploadHandler() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/images";
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY+"<BR>");
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try {
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for(FileItem item: multiparts){
                    if(item.isFormField()){
                        String name= item.getFieldName();
                        String value= item.getString();
                        out.println(name+":"+value+"</br>");
                    }else{
                        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        item.write(new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY+File.separator+name));
                        out.println("File upload Success");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
            request.setAttribute("msg", "This Servlet Handel Only Servlet Request");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tell us which URL you actually used to access the JSP.

Comment: What is the context path of your application? URL should be 
http://localhost:8080/applicationname/

Comment: http://localhost:8080/HypoThesis/Result.jsp

Comment: http://localhost:8080/HypoThesis/Index.jsp  . this is my  url